# Multiple JAXBContext instances

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

By using XJC, I create 2 different JAXB metadata packages with an ObjectFactory class in each package (I dont know if this approach is OK, I have 2 different XSD's to work on )

It is recommended to create only one JAXBContext per operation, because it is costy. So I wonder if what I'm doing here is valid and good practise?

```
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.package.one");
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller1 = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

    JAXBContext jaxbContext2 = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.package.two");
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller2 = jaxbContext2.createUnmarshaller();
```

**EDIT** when i try to initialize 2 packages together i get an exception "The element name {}Value has more than one mapping." Value is a class in both packages.

```
 JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.package.one:com.package.two");
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From the Javadoc for JAXBContext:

```
A client application normally obtains new instances of this class using one of these
two styles for newInstance methods, although there are other specialized forms of the
method available:

JAXBContext.newInstance( "com.acme.foo:com.acme.bar" )
The JAXBContext instance is initialized from a list of colon separated Java package
names. Each java package contains JAXB mapped classes, schema-derived classes and/or
user annotated classes. Additionally, the java package may contain JAXB package annotations
that must be processed. (see JLS 3rd Edition, Section 7.4.1. Package Annotations).

JAXBContext.newInstance( com.acme.foo.Foo.class )
The JAXBContext instance is intialized with class(es) passed as parameter(s) and
classes that are statically reachable from these class(es). See newInstance(Class...)
for details.
```

You can use a shared context and initialize it with a list of package names.

Code Example:

```
package test.jaxb.one;

@XMLRootElement
@XMLType(name = "test.jaxb.one.SimpleObject")
@XMLAccessorType(XMLAccessType.FIELD)
public class SimpleObject implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 54536613717262557148L;

    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    // Constructor, Setters/Getters
}
```

and this one:

```
package test.jaxb.two;

@XMLRootElement
@XMLType(name = "test.jaxb.two.SimpleObject")
@XMLAccessorType(XMLAccessType.FIELD)
public class SimpleObject implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4073071224211934153L;

    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    // Constructor, Setters/Getters
}
```

Finally:

```
public class JAXBTest {
    @Test
    public void testContextLoad() throws Exception {
        final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
            .newInstance("test.jaxb.one:test.jaxb.two");
        Assert.assertNotNull(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: thnx so its not a problem that those packages to contain classes with same name?

Comment: JAXB uses FQN (fully qualified names) while processing, so no, its not a problem if classes have the same (simple) name.

Comment: @Perception when i try to initialize 2 packages together i get an exception "The element name {}Value has more than one mapping." But they work well seperatly. Value is a class in both packages. So whats is the problem?

Comment: @tibtof - The OP already realizes that creating multiple JAXB context objects is the wrong approach, my answer tells him ***how*** to use one context and accomplish the same goal. The intent is clear.

Comment: @Spring - are you getting the exception when initializing the JAXB context, or when executing the unmarshal?

Comment: @Perception I get exception while initializing the JAXB context. Tested by removing the unmarshall code

Comment: @tibtof tnx could you give a reference on sharing same JAXB context is trouble when unmarshalling?

Comment: @tibtof changing namespaces solved the crash. But do you have a reference on your claim that "FQN is only valid for marshalling?" you can edit your answer with this information and i will remove the downvote

Comment: @Spring - you just need to add an XMLType annotation to the top of the classes with the same simple name. I would recommend using the FQN as the type name.

Comment: I changed the namespaces from objectFactory classes, is that a bad approach?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19592/discussion-between-perception-and-spring)